# Anaconda macOS GUI installation changes - should I remove the old folder in the current user account?

Tags: install, python

I have updated Anaconda by doing a fresh download and install of the macOS Graphical (GUI) version.  Anaconda is a package the makes it easier for GUI users to access python packages and use them, rather than doing so from within Terminal.

For reasons I can not identify the Navigator application would no longer open, leading me to reinstall with the latest version of the Anaconda package from the Continuum website at [this webpage.](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#osx) I have not updated my macOS recently or made any other changes that might trigger this.

The newer updated Anaconda package would not install in my user folder as it has in the past. Rather it would only install on the HD, top level. That is the new Anaconda folder sits on the same level as the Applications Folder, and Master Library Folder.

The question is, should I delete the older Anaconda folder in the User account folder structure?

As a test I have removed that folder to the Desktop, and Anaconda appears to load normally.

Naturally I should remove any saved older Jupyter or other files so as to not lose them.

The program I use the Anaconda package for is GLUE. I note my past glue project files will not open anymore in GLUE.

I am also puzzled as to why this change in installation location? If you have any thoughts, perhaps leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the old folder. All seems to be working.